# How to evaluate the following importer intergal?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Evaluate the integral $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+25)(2+\cos x)}.$$
I know how to integrate
both the integrals
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+25) }, \ \ \ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{2+\cos x}.$$
Is it any way to utilize the above integrals or please tell me how to proceed?

Comment: Guess there is no way to express it as an analytic function. Only way is to approximate numerically...

Comment: I would see if there was any A & B such that $\frac{A}{x^2 + 26} + \frac{B}{2 + \cos(x)} = \frac{1}{(x^2 + 25)(2 + \cos(x))}$.  Probably not, though.

Comment: I think the only way to evaluate is using residue theorem. Do you know it?

Comment: Yes I know about it.

Comment: Consider the integral with extrema $\pm \infty$: to evaluate it you have to compute the poles solving for $\cos z +2 = 0$ and $z^2+25 =0$. You will get infinitely many poles. Then you will get infinitely many residues, and compute the series.

Comment: Answer seems difficult: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F%28%28x%5E2%2B25%29*%282%2Bcos%28x%29%29%29+from+0+to+infinity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\alpha = -2 + \sqrt{3}$, $\beta = -2 - \sqrt{3}$ and $u = e^{ix}$. For real $x$, we have:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2 + \cos x} 
&= \frac{1}{2 + \frac{u + u^{-1}}{2}} = \frac{2u}{u^2+4u+1}\\
&= \frac{2u}{(u-\alpha)(u-\beta)} = \frac{2}{\alpha-\beta}\left(\frac{\alpha}{u-\alpha} - \frac{\beta}{u-\beta}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\Re\left(\frac{\alpha}{u-\alpha} - \frac{\beta}{u-\beta}\right)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\Re\left(\frac{\alpha}{\bar{u}-\alpha} - \frac{\beta}{u-\beta}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\Re\left(\frac{\beta^{-1}}{u^{-1}-\beta^{-1}} - \frac{\beta}{u-\beta}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\Re\left(\frac{\beta + e^{ix}}{\beta - e^{ix}}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Using this, we can transform the integral at hand as

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} \stackrel{def}{=} &\;
\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2 + 5^2)(2+\cos x)}
= \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2 + 5^2)(2+\cos x)}\\
= &\;\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^2+5^2}\frac{\beta + e^{iz}}{\beta - e^{iz}}dz
\end{align}
$$
Notice $|\beta| > 1$ and $|e^{iz}| \le 1$ for $\Im z \ge 0$. The factor
$\frac{\beta + e^{iz}}{\beta - e^{iz}}$ is holomorphic and bounded over upper half plane.
We can evaluate $\mathcal{I}$ by completing the contour in upper half plane and then take the residue at $5i$, the only pole of the integrand. The end result  is

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}
\Re\left(2\pi i \mathop{\rm Res}\limits_{z=5i}\left[\frac{1}{z^2+5^2}\frac{\beta + e^{iz}}{\beta-e^{iz}}\right]\right)
= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\Re\left(\frac{2\pi i}{10i}\frac{\beta + e^{-5}}{\beta - e^{-5}}\right)\\
&= \frac{\pi}{10\sqrt{3}}\frac{2+\sqrt{3} - e^{-5}}{2+\sqrt{3} + e^{-5}}
\approx 0.180726180098288\ldots
\end{align}
$$